# Yii - creating absolute URLs with CHTML::link()

Tags: php, html, yii, yii-chtml

I've used the CHTML::link() to create links however it doesn't seem to work for absolute URLs

My Code:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/image.png'), array('/http://www.newsite.com/about/'));?>
```

The link returns the site baseUrl so it appears like this

```
http://currentsitecom/http://www.newsite.com/about/
```

Can anyone suggest why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link shouldn't have `/` before `http://`

```
<?php echo CHtml::link(
    CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/image.png'),
    array('http://www.newsite.com/about/')
);?>
```